# I need an assistance in finding new word driven out of "Neutralization" word

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, terminology

I need help in finding the most suitable words derived from the word *neutralization*. I am using the word *neutralization* to describe a particular mathematical situation where the problem can be resolved rather than solving it. Can I use the word *neutralizable* to refer to that situation as in *this problem is neutralizable*, and if yes, which one is the more suitable word:

> This problem is unneutralizable.

or

> This problem is un-neutralizable.

or

> This problem is inneutralizable.

Comment: "This problem cannot be neutralized."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The antonym for neutralizable would be **unneutralizable**.

> *unneutralized*
>
> *ADJECTIVE*
>   Not neutralized, not rendered neutral.
>
> [Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/unneutralized)

So the correct example would be your first one:

> This problem is unneutralizable